# Fullpage.JS: Change Animation on afterSlideLoad when Swiping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

**CONTEXT / PROBLEM**

I have a fullpage.js section with 6 slides. The first slide is an index of the other 5 slides. I managed to get the first action (clicking on any of the 5 slide links in the index) to load the slide with a fade-in effect (as opposed to the swiping one).

However, once any slide is open, I need a swiping transition to take place when switching between slides (by swiping left/right). Right now, the same effect (fade-in/fade-out) overwrites this transition. I know this is because of my general statement which only checks the index in the afterSlideLoad but not sure how I can activate it only when the action is taken from the index slide.

**SO FAR**

This is what i have so far:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  css3: true,
    // Hide the slides container before the next slide loads
    onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
      if(index == 3 || index == 4){
        $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(0);
        $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').hide();
      }
    },

    // Display the slides container by fading it in after the next slide has been loaded.
    afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
      if(index == 3 || index == 4){
        $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').fadeIn(700);
        $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(SCROLLING_SPEED);
        }
    },

}
```

This is what I use to get from the index to one of the slides.

```
  $(".button1").click(function() {
    $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('sectino1', 1); //move to index of grills
    $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').hide(); //hide current slide
  });
```

This is what I use to move between the slides once one is open.

```
 $(".slide-left").click(function() {
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();
    $('.fp-section').find('.fp-slidesContainer').hide(); //hide current slide
  });
```

**JS FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/28/

Comment: For any question you ask, adding a reproduction of the issue online in jsfiddle or codepen will increase your chances of getting answers.

Comment: thanks @Alvaro : here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/28/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use the [function `silentMoveTo`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#silentmovetosection-slide) provided by fullpage.js?

I don't see why you should be adding a fadeIn or fadeOut effect if what you want is just to scroll directly to the destination.

[Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/31/) in any case. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much @Alvaro - spot on! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help @alvaro - I’m also trying to put a close button on each slide (which fades you back into index slide) but am having trouble. for some reason, i can’t reproduce on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0hLzxrea/32/ but on my site, clicking close scrolls you bak to start. Is there a way to add conditional so that if destination slide is index, then there’s no scroll?